# API to retrieve recent commits

Tags: git, api, gerrit, gitweb

I have some project using a git repository with gerrit and gitweb available on the web. I am looking for an API via which I can do an HTTP request to get the commits made in the last 10 seconds. Currently I am using some github API of a mirror of the repo, though the replag there is over a minute, forcing me to do requests for commits from the last 2 mins if I want anything to show up. Do either gitweb or gerrit provide an API I can use? And if not, are there other alternatives that do not require much work?

Solution found:

Using the API described here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html

Doing a query using the "age" restriction, which returns commits at least as old as the specified age. This can be revered by negating the condition which is done by prefixing its name with a -. This is further explained here https://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3021/documentation/2.1.4/user-search.html#search_operators

So my query for the first change merged in the last 10 seconds is this:
https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/changes/?q=status:merged+project:mediawiki/extensions/Wikibase+-age:10s&n=1

Comment: If you want to build your own tool, here is a good place to start: http://libgit2.github.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html

Cheers

Rasmus Voss

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I was looking for! Took me a bit to figure out if it was possible to do the query I wanted though.

Comment: Hey Jeroen , Do you know how to use these APIs in script??  Need some help..